# How to create a virtual monitor for VR?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr

I'm using Immersed for the oculus quest 2, which isn't currently supporting multiple virtual monitors for me. I have a little headless ghost hdmi dongle, but it's not customizable, and a bit of a hassle to keep track of. I'd like to have multiple monitors within the vr workspace.

I need something like a software dummy HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the arch wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Extreme_Multihead#VNC).

The commands that worked for me were:

```bash
gtf 1920 1080 60
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode "1920x1080_60.00" --right-of eDP-1 --auto
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode "1920x1080_60.00" --right-of eDP-1 --auto
sudo -s
echo on > /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/HDMI-A-2/force
```

Comment: Did this work for displaying multiple views in Immersed?